# How to resolve MISRA C:2012 Rule 21.4?

Tags: setjmp

I am using setjmp and longjmp in our code with standard library [#include <setjmp.h>]. When I am trying to use it showing following MISRA error: **Violation of MISRA C:2012 21.4: The standard header file <setjmp.h> shall not be used. and Use of lonjmp() is not recommended because it is correlated with security or safety problems.** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8E3Z.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dlOh.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Switch off the 21.4 rule check or don't use any setjmp operations.